# Array numbers in order

Tags: c#, arrays

In my main I have this array with random numbers

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int [] numbers = new int[] { 1, 6, 4, 11, 2, 5, 9, 3, 7, 10, 12, 8 };

        Console.WriteLine("The scores are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I need to make a static method in a class that would rearrange these numbers so that they are in order and I'm not sure how to do this. I need to swap these numbers.

Comment: any reason why you can't use a list<T>? (List<int>)

Answer (score 9):

Use [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to sort your original array:

```
Array.Sort(numbers);
```

Or [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create new sorted sequence, which you can save to array:

```
int[] sorted = numbers.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
```

Comment: Not meaning to be an troll, but this doesn't actually answer the question. He said he's not sure how to create a static method to do this.

Comment: @AshleyMedway not meaning to be a troll, but he wants array numbers in order :) I believe this is main point of question, not static methods, not console programs, or C# syntax

Comment: I do agree thats the main point :) This is more of a homework (just give me the answer) question though +1

Answer (score 4):

[`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class has a [`Sort method (Array)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes array as a parameter.

> Sorts the elements in an entire one-dimensional Array using the
>   IComparable implementation of each element of the Array.

Here am example with [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net);

```
void Main()
{
    int [] numbers = new int[] { 1, 6, 4, 11, 2, 5, 9, 3, 7, 10, 12, 8 };
    ReturnSortedArray(numbers);
    foreach (var element in numbers)
    {
        element.Dump();
    }
}
static void ReturnSortedArray(Array a)
{
    Array.Sort(a);
}
```

Output will be;

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question which was how do I create a static method to sort the Array you can use the code below.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 6, 4, 11, 2, 5, 9, 3, 7, 10, 12, 8 };

    Console.WriteLine ("The scores are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (numbers [i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine ("The scores in order are: ");
    SortArray (numbers);
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine (numbers [i]);
    }

    Console.ReadLine ();
}

public static int[] SortArray(int[] arrayIn)
{
    Array.Sort (arrayIn);
    return arrayIn;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> The scores are: 
>   1 6 4 11 2 5 9 3 7 10 12 8 
>   The scores in order are: 
>   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

Answer (score 1):

you can sort in here

```
Array.Sort(numbers);
```